# How to remove a page link from Navigation menu big cartel

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the Luna Theme on Big Cartel. I've added a static 'Thank you' page for signing up to the newsletter. However the link appears in the footer navigation menu. How do I remove the link from the menu?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a specific page from the footer navigation in the Luna theme, you can head to Customize Design > Advanced > Layout in the admin, and click the "Custom" button to enable code editing.

Scroll down almost all the way to the bottom, and you'll see this block of code:

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
  <li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To exclude a specific page, you can modify that block - if your page is titled "Thank You", this code will only display every other page:

```
{% for page in pages.all %}
  {% if page.name != 'Thank You' %}<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```